# What is the best/most efficient DBMS for a social networking website?

Tags: mysql, sql, web, relational-database, database

I want to build a social networking site and I was wondering what is the best DBMS to use for such a site.

I know this question has been asked a million times and always with the same pretentious arrogance of a newbie: *I want the "BEST" for MY site!* :-)

I also understand that there is no "BEST" in this scenario. Every developer imagines/likes their data to be structured/related/stored in a different way. But I don't know from where to begin being a newbie. I know mySQL is probably the most popular, I keep hearing about MongoDB, CouchDB, Cassandra..

I like the idea of a relational database. It makes sense, it's natural, human. But being a programmer/web developer I work with classes, objects, keys and properties and I believe a database should reflect that object-oriented character. I think noSQL types of databases work like that although I'm not sure how. However, it makes more sense to me that if I'm building/using objects in my code, objects with nested objects and arrays and I want to store these in a database, I might as well store them in a similar/equivalent fashion.

Anyway, could someone point me to the right direction because I need to start off somewhere and see where that takes me anyway! :-)

By the way, stupid newbie question coming your way right now : If I build the database and the website, but decide that I should go with a different database after all, is such a thing as a "migration" (e.g. from mySQL to noSQL and vice versa) possible for a live website or a nightmare?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First it depends on the technologie u are using for ur social networking site.
I will try to help u from my experience in .Net technology.

Making ur database object-oriented and independant from DBMS could be achieved using Entity Framework. Hibernate offers also such possibilities for java language, but cant compare the two technologies.

Now for the DBMS, as u said there are multiples choices, but the choice depends on their data use, update frequency, requests, number of expected users,... and also it is possible to use multiple DBMS depending on that constraints.

For example, when ure using cached user data, i suggest to use SQLite to free the server memory, it can also be used for parameters Data (can be used with the Entity Framework).
For hitorical Data, SQL Server can be a good choise.
MySQL can also be used for most frequent data.

U see, there is not a "BEST CHOISE" for ur technology, all depends on ur needs and constraints.

Hope will help.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Mongi. The language I will be using is Javascript, both client-side & server-side(Node.js). I've been reading quite a lot online and I'm starting to lean towards MongoDB. However, I still haven't found a comprehensive guide for MongoDB. Thanks a lot for your advice.